# Find directory path (recursive) matching directory name

Tags: php

I have the following directory structure:

```
/mnt/disk/documents
/mnt/disk/data/files/
/mnt/disk/data/morefiles/
```

The mount point `disk/` is variable. I need to get all files from `data/` and it's sub directories. I know how to list files with `glob` but in this case I need first find the directory `data` and than all files recursively.

How can I do that, not knowing the full path from the beginning?

Comment: simple use realpath ( string $path );

Comment: Why don't you know the full path? How is the mount point, `disk` in this case, injected to your  script?

Comment: The user will mount a device under /mnt, this will create a mount point. I dont know the name of the moutpoint, but I know that there is a directory called 'data' on the device.

Answer (score 0):

One way.

```
realpath ( string $path );
```

realpath() expands all symbolic links and resolves references to '/./', '/../' and extra '/' characters in the input path and returns the canonicalized absolute pathname.

Example:

PHP:

```
 <?php
    echo realpath('/windows/system32');

    echo realpath('C:\Program Files\\');
    ?>
```

Result:

```
C:\WINDOWS\System32
C:\Program Files
```

Simple way. Any questions, just ask that I will try to answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't know whats the directory within /mnt/. It could be /mnt/disk, /mnt/disk1, or another directory name. I don't see how I can find the directory 'data' within a variable sub folder in /mnt using realpath.

Comment: You can get the current working directory if it helps. "getcwd();" — Gets the current working directory see more in this link: http://php.net/manual/en/function.getcwd.php

Comment: Thanks @Jose, but I'm not looking for that.